# How to make plot3d box axis the same length?

Tags: r

Sorry all, I finally found the answer. Here is the original question:

I wrote a code where a surface comes and lay in a plot3d box. My Surface x values have 2427 meters lenght (ranging from 600000 to 602427), 1774 meters lenght for my y's (ranging from 5600000 to 5601774) and my z's have a 345 meters length (ranging from 0 to 345).

Since the plot3d box is a squared, the surface that lays in the box does not represent the realistic scale and form of what I want to represent. Is there a way to make the box axis all of the same lenght, say all 3 axis having a 2427 meters length, where I can chose the min and max value of each axis?

Also, when ploting only the surface3d, the axis scaling seems to represent the realistic form!

Here is my code:

```
drilling_trial<- read.table("DRILLING_TRIAL.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
all_pit_data<- read.table("ALL_PIT_DATA.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
require("akima")
s <- with(all_pit_data,interp(x1,y1,z1))
library("rgl")
plot3d(drilling_trial$x,drilling_trial$y,drilling_trial$z,
       col = drilling_trial$d,
       add = FALSE,
       axes = TRUE,
       bbox = TRUE,
       xlab="x",
       ylab="y",
       zlab="z")
cols <- heat.colors(462)
surface3d(s$x,s$y,s$z,
          color=cols[s$z])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys... I am quite new in programming r and I did not think about that first! here is what I did!

Cheers

```
drilling_trial<- read.table("DRILLING_TRIAL.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
all_pit_data<- read.table("ALL_PIT_DATA.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
require("akima")
s <- with(all_pit_data,interp(x1,y1,z1))
library("rgl")
plot3d(drilling_trial$x,drilling_trial$y,drilling_trial$z, 
       col = drilling_trial$d, 
       xlim = c(611500,614000), 
       ylim = c(5420000,5422500), 
       zlim = c(0,2500), 
       add = FALSE, 
       axes = TRUE, 
       bbox = TRUE, 
       xlab="x", 
       ylab="y", 
       zlab="z")
cols <- heat.colors(462)
surface3d(s$x,s$y,s$z,
      color=cols[s$z])
```